# Break loop using hotkey

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-interface

There are hundreds of similar questions but none of them appear to be a solution in my case.
My code is shaped in this way

```
def iterative_func():
    # do things
while True:
    iterative_func()
```

Then I would like it to stop when I press a hotkey let's say 'ctrl+k'.
I tried `pynput` but the listener is not applicable since it waits for an Input and the rest of the script (`iterative_func()`) won't run, in my case the script should continuously run until I press some hotkey.
Also the solution

```
while True:
    try:
        iterative_func()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

doesn't work for me (I don't know why, but maybe it's because I'm running VSCode), anyway it's not code I want to implement because the script will be deployed as a .exe file.

PS.
I cannot import `Key` and `Controller` from `pynput`, it prompts an error and I have no clue on how to fix this so also solutions using these should be avoided.

Comment: "it prompts an error" -> Which error? What code are you running to import this modules? Are they installed in the environment you are running?  "maybe it's because I'm running VSCode" -> so have you tried running it from console to discard that it's because of VSCode?

Comment: I don't want to use while-try-except in any case so I will not test it outside of vscode. As for the error it  is simply: ''cannot import name 'Key' from 'pynput' " even though pynput is correctly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried pynput but the listener is not applicable since it waits for
> an Input and the rest of the script (iterative_func()) won't run

I can shed some light on how to overcome this problem, which made you optout `pynput`. See the below approach:

```
from pynput import keyboard

running = True  # flag on loop runs


def stop_run():  # function to stop the program
    global running
    running = False


# register a hotkey, and call stop_run() when it is pressed
with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<ctrl>+k': stop_run}) as h:
    while running:
        print("Running ... ")
```

This will run your code and wait for hotkey to stop the loop by a flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the code is also very clear to me.